# Lydia unequipping armor when dismissed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got lydia as a follower and have been doing some quest with her. I decided to give her my orcish armor so she can tank better for me but now i have a problem. Every time i dismiss her she Unequips her armor and is just naked. I tried taking away the orcish armor to see if see reverts back to her steel armor but it doesn't work she is still walking around nude. I have already try the disable, enable, and rest AI commands but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with having a naked woman walk around?

Comment: Do you have any plugins enabled?  What platform?

Comment: Check out a mod on PC called "Advanced Follower Tweaks" on the Skyrim Nexus.  It will allow you to permanently remove default clothes and armor and give them whatever you want them to wear.  They won't change out of the armor you give them if you remove everything else from their inventory.